# PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, sequence, plpgsql

I've created this function to re-sequence the sequence number on a BOM table (bomitem).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seqincr(integer)
  RETURNS SETOF bomitem AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  pItemid ALIAS FOR $1;
  _row bomitem%ROWTYPE;
  seqint int;
  _id int;


BEGIN
  seqint=8;
  FOR _row IN SELECT *
            FROM bomitem
            WHERE ((bomitem_parent_item_id=pItemid))
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT _row;
    _id = _row.bomitem_id;
    seqint = seqint+2;
    update bomitem set bomitem_seqnumber = seqint where bomitem_id=_id;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION  seqincr(integer)
  OWNER TO admin;
```

The example works on an individual `bomitem_parent_item_id` like below:

```
SELECT * from seqincr(14917);
```

I would like to rewrite this function to loop through

```
SELECT distinct bomitem_parent_item_id FROM bomitem;
```

so that it resequences the entire BOM table.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is much simpler with a CTE:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT bomitem_parent_item_id
         , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY bomitem_parent_item_id) AS rn
    FROM   bomitem
    GROUP  BY bomitem_parent_item_id
    ORDER  BY bomitem_parent_item_id
    )
UPDATE bomitem b
SET    bomitem_seqnumber = 8 + 2 * rn
FROM   x
WHERE  x.bomitem_parent_item_id = b.bomitem_id;
```

You need at least **PostgreSQL 9.1** for [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

Or use a subquery, works in earlier versions, too:

```
UPDATE bomitem b
SET    bomitem_seqnumber = 8 + 2 * rn
FROM  (
    SELECT bomitem_parent_item_id
         , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY bomitem_parent_item_id) AS rn
    FROM   bomitem
    GROUP  BY bomitem_parent_item_id
    ORDER  BY bomitem_parent_item_id
    ) x
WHERE  x.bomitem_parent_item_id = b.bomitem_id;
```

But you need at least **PostgreSQL 8.4** for the [**window function** `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html).

Comment: Sorry I took so long to notice your answer.  Thanks for taking the time.  What happens with your solution is that each of the components of a bill of materials gets the same bomitem_seqnumber.  Each new bill of material gets the next higher integer corresponding to the number of the group.  What I need is to have each bomitem_seqnumber incremented so that the first component in the bill has a bomitem_seqnumber of 10, the next 12, the next 14 etc.  My function work great except that is not iterative across the entire bomitem table.

Comment: Hi can you maybe also help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318816/function-for-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment75643213_44318816 ? Thanks